# Previous Row data Using KendoUi MVC Grid - Razor-C#

Tags: c#, kendo-grid, mvcgrid

I have a Grid (Razor-c#) Containing multiple columns/rows and there is a column named **profit/loss** .For every row I need to check the previous row data from profit/loss column and make some calculation to put the values in the current row profit/loss column

**UPDATE**

```
Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.accountHistory).Name("History").Columns(c =>
 {


     c.Bound(p => p.datetimecalculated).Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}");
     c.Bound("").ClientTemplate("#= purchaseCriteria(data) #").Title(" ");
     c.Bound(p => p.numcontracts).ClientTemplate("#= moneyFormat(numcontDFracts) #");
     c.Bound(p => p.entityid);
     c.Bound(p => p.leagueid);
     c.Bound("")
         .ClientTemplate("#= setSeasonYear(data) #")
         .Sortable(false)
         .Title("Year");

     c.Bound("")
         .ClientTemplate("#= setSeason(data) #")
         .Sortable(false)
         .Title("Season");
     c.Bound(p => p.contractmeasurable);
     c.Bound(p => p.price).ClientTemplate("#= moneyformat_at(DDEDE) #");
     c.Bound(p => p.profitorloss).ClientTemplate("#= moneyFormat(profitorloss) #");
     c.Bound(p => p.cashBalance).ClientTemplate("#= moneyFormat_diff(cashBalance) #");

 }).DataSource(
d => d
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(false)

)
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
        )
```

Comment: what you have tried so far? can you share your code?

Comment: @MusakkhirSayyed I updated my question . kindly have a look at that